# Simple Network at Church

Tags: networking

We are updating out streaming system at church adding a second computer for streaming only and a new PTZ camera that can send video over Lan. Only problem, we don't have a Lan. I only want to connect the camera and the two computers together to share the camera and bring videos from the old computer. Do I need a wired router or can I just use a smart switch to do that? Right now we are using a wireless internet. We will not be hooking up to the wired system since the wireless modem is on the other end of the building.

Comment: So you're planning for the computer to be connected to Wi-Fi for Internet and wired LAN for camera at the same time?

Comment: Hopefully. Will need internet for the streaming computer but a lan between everything to share the NDI streaming camera and a stream from the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need a wired router or can I just use a smart switch to do that?

Neither; any cheap unmanaged switch will do.

("Smart" switches add various management features, but none of those are needed for a basic LAN.)

If the LAN will not have any Internet connection, then a router is *mostly* useless. You'd be only using its built-in LAN switch, no different from an external switch.

(It can still be convenient to have a router for the sole purpose of using its DHCP server for automatic IP address assignment – but it'll also advertise itself as a gateway to the Internet, whether it actually has an Internet connection or not, and that might confuse your PC if you're planning to connect it simultaneously to Wi-Fi and the wired LAN.)

Comment: "_it'll also advertise itself as a gateway to the Internet_" not all routers do this; there is at least one brand of SOHO router that can be configured either way (I use them extensively for work)

Comment: Yes, in theory, a DHCP server should be easily configurable for this (it's just a matter of adding or removing the DHCP lease option)... but the huge majority of "home" routers don't offer that kind of configurability.